# when netty's io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet hold too much selectionkeyimpl can't be gced?

Tags: netty, nio

I have one test for my application:

connect and send several messages out offormat and close the connect, repeat the steps for one day.

After one day of the test and I click GC, I found the SelectedSelectionKeySet still hold too much selectionkeyimpl (over 149645 items)?

I don't under when I can encounter this case:

the item 0-537  is null instead of selectionkeyimpl so that the latter part can't be consumed.

after the item after about 537 in my case is selectionkeyimpl.

my special decode is： so every message out of format will call "return null";

```
public class FrameDecoder extends DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FrameDecoder .class);

    private static final int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 10*1024*1024;

    public DsAgentFrameDecoder() {
        super(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(CodecConstants.FRAME_TAILER.getBytes()));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) super.decode(ctx, buffer);

        try{

            if (byteBuf == null) {
                if(LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                    LOG.debug("[tcp][receive]bytebuf is null");
                return null;
            }
```

here is the heap dump:

[image: there are too many objects and the first 0-537's element is null instead of selectionkeyimpl so that the latter part can't be consumed.]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is netty's bug, and I had fix it : https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/4673